# AngularJS get JSON data from more than one Service

Tags: angularjs

I have two Services **getCountUp** and **getCountDown**. I want to get JSON data from both services.

My controller code is given below

```
(function () {
    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('VisitorsController', [ 'getHostStatusService', VisitorsController])
        .factory("getHostStatusService", ['$http', function($http) {
            return {
                getResponders: function(servicesUrl) {
                    return $http.get(servicesUrl).then(function(response) {
                        console.log(response.data);
                        return response.data;
                    });
                }
            };
            return getHostStatusService;
        }]);

    function VisitorsController(getHostStatusService) {
        var vm = this;
        var servicesUrl = app.serviceCallUrl+'getCountUp';

        var getCountUp = 0;
        var getCountDown = 0;

        console.log(servicesUrl);
        getHostStatusService.getResponders(servicesUrl).then(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            getCountUp = data;
        });

        var servicesUrl1 = app.serviceCallUrl+'getCountDown';
        console.log(servicesUrl1);
        getHostStatusService.getResponders(servicesUrl1).then(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            getCountDown = data;
        });
    }
})();
```

In my Console I am getting the following error

```
GET http://localhost:8080/getCountDown 500 ()
Possibly unhandled rejection: {"data":"<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/8.5.8 - Error report</title><style type=\"text/css\">H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}.line {height: 1px; background-color: #525D76; border: none;}</style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: Transaction not successfully started</h1><div class=\"line\"></div><p><b>type</b> Exception report</p><p><b>message</b> <u>Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: Transaction not successfully started</u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.</u></p><p><b>exception</b></p><pre>org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: Transaction not successfully started\n\torg.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)\n\torg.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)\n\tjavax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)\n\torg.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)\n\tjavax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)\n\torg.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)\n\tcom.alleviateconsultancy.nms.configuration.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:25)\n</pre><p><b>root cause</b></p><pre>org.hibernate.TransactionException: Transaction not successfully started\n\torg.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:172)\n\tcom.alleviateconsultancy.nms.dao.NMSDaoImp.getServiceHostCountDown(NMSDaoImp.java:574)\n\tcom.alleviateconsultancy.nms.service.NMSDaoServiceImp.getServiceHostCountDown(NMSDaoServiceImp.java:106)\n\tsun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\n\tsun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\n\tsun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\n\tjava.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)\n\torg.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302)\n\torg.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)\n\torg.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)\n\torg.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)\n\torg.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)\n\torg.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)\n\torg.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)\n\torg.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)\n\tcom.sun.proxy.$Proxy41.getServiceHostCountDown(Unknown Source)\n\tcom.alleviateconsultancy.nms.controller.AppController.getHostCountDown(AppController.java:141)\n\tsun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\n\tsun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\n\tsun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\n\tjava.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)\n\torg.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)\n\torg.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)\n\torg.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:111)\n\torg.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:806)\n\torg.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:729)\n\torg.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)\n\torg.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)\n\torg.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)\n\torg.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)\n\torg.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)\n\tjavax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)\n\torg.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)\n\tjavax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)\n\torg.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)\n\tcom.alleviateconsultancy.nms.configuration.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:25)\n</pre><p><b>note</b> <u>The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/8.5.8 logs.</u></p><hr class=\"line\"><h3>Apache Tomcat/8.5.8</h3></body></html>","status":500,"config":{"method":"GET","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"jsonpCallbackParam":"callback","url":"http://localhost:8080/getCountDown","headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"}},"statusText":""}
```

But this is not working. I always get JSON data from only one service.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong in here... Why don't you try putting error callbacks in the promises to see if maybe there's any call failing? Or can you check the browser network debugger to check if the calls are being sent?

Comment: The data you are getting, is from which service - Url or Url1 ?

Comment: @Subhajit From servicesUrl.

Comment: @olivarra1 How can I use promises into this?

Comment: @olivarra1 I update my error on my post question, which I am getting on my console.

Comment: That looks like a server error: 500. The server is not giving any JSON data for that call. You see that `data` field? It's what the server is sending, a webpage with the details of the server error.

Comment: @olivarra1 I am able to get data by both services if I am using only one Service at a time. That means If I remove code for servicesUrl than I am getting servicesUrl1 data and If I remove servicesUrl1 than I am getting servicesUrl data.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be at the server end, like it can't deal with multiple requests at the same time or something (which is pretty bad in general). So you should probably deal with that.

You can likely bypass the problem by only doing one server request at a time as follows:

```
function VisitorsController(getHostStatusService) {
    var vm = this;
    var servicesUrl = app.serviceCallUrl+'getCountUp';
    var servicesUrl1 = app.serviceCallUrl+'getCountDown';

    var getCountUp = 0;
    var getCountDown = 0;

    getHostStatusService.getResponders(servicesUrl)
    .then(function(data) {
        getCountUp = data;
        return getHostStatusService.getResponders(servicesUrl1)
    })
    .then(function(data) {
        getCountDown = data;
    });
}
```

Comment: In this case If I am getting any exception from servicesUrl than I am not getting any data from servicesUrl1 also?

Comment: @user3441151 Then also put `return getHostStatusService.getResponders(servicesUrl1)` in the error callback of the first `.then(`

Comment: But take @fissio advice: Something really wrong is happening on the server. You should try to fix that side.

Answer (score 0):

You have made multiple return statement in your factory method

Use the below code, for the demo purpose I have used Json files.

```
app.controller('VisitorsController', [ 'getHostStatusService', VisitorsController]);

  function VisitorsController(getHostStatusService) {
        var vm = this;
        var servicesUrl = 'getCountUp.json';

        var getCountUp = 0;
        var getCountDown = 0;

        console.log(servicesUrl);
        getHostStatusService.getResponders(servicesUrl).then(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            getCountUp = data;
        });

        var servicesUrl1 = 'getCountDown.json';
        console.log(servicesUrl1);
        getHostStatusService.getResponders(servicesUrl1).then(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            getCountDown = data;
        });
    }
app.factory("getHostStatusService", ['$http', function($http) {
            return {
                getResponders: function(servicesUrl) {
                    return $http.get(servicesUrl).then(function(response) {
                        console.log(response.data);
                        return response.data;
                    });
                }
            };
        }]);
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/P6dRFeP1CDdHTRAG6Muv)**

Comment: Although it is a code smell, it really doesn't matter. The second return won't be ever called.

Comment: I think you are aware of the factory concept in angular which forces a return statement, if not please do refer it. so the second statement is force executed.

Comment: With all respect, AngularJS is a Javascript framework. It doesn't change the way JS gets executed. If in JS in a function you have `return 1; return 2;` you will allways get `1` as return value, and `return 2` statement won't ever be executed. Try putting a `console.log` in between, even in a AngularJS aplication.